# Find, Find Next?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, find

I am trying to make a find, find next function for my program, which I did manage to do with this code:

```
 int findPos = 0;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string s = textBox1.Text;
            richTextBox1.Focus();
            findPos = richTextBox1.Find(s, findPos, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
            richTextBox1.Select(findPos, s.Length);
            findPos += textBox1.Text.Length;
            //i = richTextBox1.Find(s, i + s.Length, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Occurences Found");
            findPos = 0;
        }
    }
```

And it works great in form1 but if I use this code and try to call it from form2 It doesn't do anything:

```
  //Form1
  public void FindNext()
    {
        try
        {
            this.Focus();
            Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
            string s = frm2.textBox1.Text;
            richTextBox1.Focus();
            findPos = richTextBox1.Find(s, findPos, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
            richTextBox1.Select(findPos + 1, s.Length);
            findPos += textBox1.Text.Length;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Occurences Found");
            findPos = 0;
        }
    }

 //Form2
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        frm1.FindNext();
    }
```

Does any one know why this is?
Thanks,Tanner.

Comment: **Please** name your forms and controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be confused in how you reference `Form1` and `Form2` from each other.

Calling `new Form()` and `new Form2()` create references to *new* instances of `Form1` and `Form2`, they don't reference the forms that are already open. You need to get the references for the *existing* instances.

Assuming that `Form1` is the main form for your application and it creates and shows `Form2`, you can either add a property to `Form2` that represents the instance of `Form1` that created it, or you can appropriate the `Owner` property for this purpose (I'd recommend that).

In your code on `Form1` that shows `Form2` initially (not in the code you have above), call `frm2.Show(this)` instead of just `frm2.Show()`. This will set the `Owner` property of your `Form2` instance equal to thinstance of `Form1` that opened it.

Then change your button code for `Form2` to this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Form1 frm1 = (Form1)Owner;
    frm1.FindNext(); 
}
```

This will make you reference the existing form rather than a new one, which is what you want.

As far as the `FindNext` function goes, you have two choices: either you can hold on to the reference of `Form2` (though you probably want to do this anyway) and access the text directly, or you can change `FindNext` to take a string (this is what I'd recommend).

```
public void FindNext(string searchText)
{
    try
    {
        this.Focus();
        richTextBox1.Focus();
        findPos = richTextBox1.Find(searchText, findPos, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
        richTextBox1.Select(findPos + 1, searchText.Length);
        findPos += searchText.Length;
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Occurences Found");
        findPos = 0;
    }
}
```

Then change the call to `frm1.FindNext()` on `Form2` to `frm1.FindNext(textBox1.Text)`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Form1 frm1 = (Form1)Owner;
    frm1.FindNext(textBox1.Text); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  string s = Interaction.InputBox("enter search text", "Notepad-search", "", 100, 100);
    //The above syntax is from vb.net so add reference as microsoft.VisualBasic from   references. The above code creates an alertbox. Then type the text which you want search and click on ok.

           int f = richTextBox1.Find(s);
           if (f >= 0)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("search Text is found");
           }
           else
           {
               MessageBox.Show("search Text is not found");
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your textbox on the new instance of frm1 will have no value surely? So there is nothing for the method to do...

Try stepping through the code and checking you actually have values to work with?

When you say:

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
```

You are creating a fresh version so any extra information thats been added you dont have when accessing frm1

Try this and you will see what I mean

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
frm1.Show();
```

When this code is excecuted you will see that you have actually made another instance of your form.

What you need to do is work with the original instance rather than create a new one, so that you still have all that information in your textboxes.

I'll leave you to work this one out, but there is you answer :)

Comment: Your correct, I just added a messagebox to return frm2.textbox1.Text and it was blank. How can I fix this?

EDIT* I got it to return a value but it still isn't working

Comment: @Tanner: You need to give `Form2` the original instance of `Form1`, and vice-versa.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

By writing `Form1 frm1 = new Form1();`, you're creating a brand-new instance of the `Form1` form, which never gets any text and is never shown to the user.

You need to pass the original `Form1` instance to `Form2` in `Form2`'s constructor.

Similarly, when you write `Form2 frm2 = new Form2();` in `FindNext`, you're making a brand-new `Form2` instance without any text.
Instead, you should pass the text as a parameter to the `FindNext` method.

For example:

```
public void FindNext(string searchText) {
    ...
    findPos = richTextBox1.Find(searchText, findPos, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
    ...
}

originalForm.FindNext(textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are referencing two different instances of Form2.

In your Form1.FindNext() you have a new instance of Form2 that you are creating and getting the text value from which is different to the instance where you are calling your FindNext() from.

What you might want to do is to pass in the instance of the form to FindNext(). So your function would be...

```
//Form1
 public void FindNext(Form2 frm2)
{
    try
    {
        this.Focus();
        string s = frm2.textBox1.Text;
        richTextBox1.Focus();
        findPos = richTextBox1.Find(s, findPos, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
        richTextBox1.Select(findPos + 1, s.Length);
        findPos += textBox1.Text.Length;
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Occurences Found");
        findPos = 0;
    }
}

//Form2
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
    frm1.FindNext(this);
 }
```